# C# - external service call - working fine in Debug, giving exception in release

Tags: .net, debugging, exception, service, release

This weird thing is happening to my C# console app. This app uses a third party service dll to talk to a database.
The issue that I face is not there in debug mode, everything is working fine and as expected.
BUT when I try to run it in Release mode, the third party service throws up an exception. I go inside the exception and the inner most exception tells me that it could not open the registry key *{registry key path related to the third party service}*.
I am running the app with an admin user so no issues in that department.
I'm not able to find much on this on the internet either.
I'm hoping someone who has faced something similar can point me to a direction here.

Since the only difference in calling that failing service is the fact that my 'calling' code is in release mode or debug mode, the best question to be asked here seems to be how the service calls differ in debug mode and release mode in dotnet code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask is a good summary of the information that's needed to write a good question; you haven't, for example, said whereabouts the registry key is or shown the code that reads it.

Comment: Hi Adrian. Thanks for pointing it out to me. But the issue I face is that the exception comes from the external service and not my code. Also the exception comes only in release mode and not debug mode. Also, the registry path is a custom path that's specific to the external service. That's what got me confused as to how should the question be framed. Let me try by asking if anybody is aware of how the service calls differ in debug mode and release mode in dotnet code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an issue with the configuration manager settings. For some reason the start-up project of the solution was having 'Platform' set to 'x86' instead of 'Any CPU'.
Changed it to 'Any CPU' and everything started working fine.
Thanks anyways guys.